# Why won't the closest() selector work in this instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to activate toggleClass() on a specific image when clicking on a radio button. I have been trying for ages to get it to work but can't. I can manage to select a parent element of the radio button but nothing proceeding it. I have tried next(), nextAll() and closest(). All of which don't seem to do what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is my jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
    if (this.value == "AM") {
      $(this).closest('img[title="am"]').toggleClass('houdini');
    } else if (this.value == "PM") {
    alert('PM');
/*      Something here */
    } else {
        return false();
    }
  });
});
```

and my HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="bisley" value="AM" />AM<input type="radio" name="bisley" value="PM" />PM<span class="compname">Bisley</span></td>
    <td>Fit more into less space</td>
    <td class="time"><img src="/images/generic/openday/tick.png" alt="tick" title="am" class="houdini" />10.00AM</td>
    <td class="time"><img src="/images/generic/openday/tick.png" alt="tick" title="pm" class="houdini" />1.30PM</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Because the `input` and the `img` are being separated by their containing `td`s and none of the functions you tried work as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) searches ancestor elements; [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) and [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) search sibling elements. The `img` element you want is the child of a sibling element, so you'll need a more complex statement.  Have a go with this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('img[title="am"]').toggleClass('houdini');
```

This says "find the closest ancestor `tr` element, then find `img[title="am"]` within that.

Comment: @BoltClock He'll get healthier when the images are next refreshed ;-)

Comment: Great. That works. Any idea on how I can toggle the class for the image using the radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
$(this).parent().children('img[title="am"]').toggleClass('houdini');
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9H8k4/)**